# How to paint surfaces in jzy3D with plain colors

Tags: java, 3d, jzy3d

I have some surfaces and I want to paint one in red, another un blue...

Tutorial of jzy3D only shows how to paint as a rainbow with [ColorMaps](http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d/wiki/Colormaps):

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I was using the same set of Polygons for each Shape object. Using differents Polygons and Shapes, it's possible to give a different color to each surface.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do that:
1) You can implement a Colormap that returns your choosen color and to provide it to the surface builder.
2) You can build the surface and then access the polygon points and edit their color object.